# remove slivers, duplicate vertices in FME

Tags: gis, geospatial, polygon, vertices, fme

Hello I am looking to implement these rules within my data:

eliminating:

1. polygons less than 1m2
2. polygons less than 1m in width
3. duplicate vertices less than 1m apart

any help is appreciated.

thanks,
Curtis

I have tried an area calculator and area selector for polygons less than 1m2

which appears to work but I wonder if there is a better method